# TestCafe scroll event not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am attempting to write a functional test to verify if a link exists an an array of elements, that the link opens successfully.

I am getting stuck within the first few steps of the test.

"testcafe": "^0.22.0"
node v8.11.2
running in chrome

I am using a client function to handle the scrolling during the test:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const scrollTo = ClientFunction(top => {
     window.scrollTo(0, top);
     window.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'))
});

fixture(`Given user is in fund story chapter 4 for symbol GOBAX`)
     .page(`http://localhost:8080/#/fund-story/gobax/5`);

test(`User verifies that the ESG report link in the tooltip of each Top Holdings ESG Scores datapoint, opens successfully`, async testController => {
     const section = Selector('#section-esg-top-holdings');
     const top = await section.offsetTop;
     await scrollTo(top);
     await testController.wait(3000);
})
```

The 'section' does exist on the page and the client function does successfully scroll to the element. I have even attempted to force the event to dispatch, yet the callback in the component is not triggered.
The callback in the component for the window scroll event triggers more elements to render on the page after doing some calculations to verify the section is in view.

If I use window.scrollTo(0, top); where top = y position of the section, inside the chrome dev tools, the event is triggered and the additional elements are rendered.

Is this a testCafe bug or am I missing something in the test that would successfully trigger the event?

Comment: It's difficult to determine the reason of the issue without a working project. I've prepared a sample project based on your test, which demonstrates that the `window.scroll` method raises an event correctly. Please check the following link https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/41e681dadf49d86833e2441f4d31d0bc

Comment: oh thats unfortunate  >_< Thank you very much for taking the time to clarify that. I will come back to post a solution when I identify the issue further with that knowledge

Comment: @JordanKlaers,
Have you managed to identify the issue and find a solution?

Comment: No, the scrolling works,  but the call back isn't updating with the data.  It's relates to a vue prop.

Answer (score 1):

I think that TestCafe can incorrectly simulate scroll events for your page. Since @AlexKamaev hasn't reproduced the problem, please create a new [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and provide a page that can be used to reproduce it.